# Router not generating template of parent component?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm attempting to migrate my routing system from the Beta/RC1 style (@angular/router-deprecated) to that which is available in RC4(@angular/router).

It seems straightforward enough, except I keep getting hung up on the concept of parent router components and children. The actual component defined in the parent path for my router never seems to have it's template displayed for some of my paths. That parent is a wrapper that contains content including the new `<router-outlet>`

My dashboard routing works just fine. It loads up the membership child initially and the wrapper content contained in the `DashboardComponent` shows up, allowing navigation to each of the children.

```
export const DashboardRoutes: RouterConfig = [
    {
        path: "dashboard",
        component: DashboardComponent,
        children: [
            { path: "", redirectTo: "membership" },
            { path: "executive", component: ExecutivePanelComponent },
            { path: "membership", component: MembershipPanelComponent }
        ]
    }
];
```

But on another navigable area of my site, it doesn't work the same. It just renders a blank screen, though the url in the browser shows correct. None of the content of the `ReportCatalogComponent` is shown.

```
export const ReportCatalogRoutes: RouterConfig = [
    {
        path: "catalog",
        component: ReportCatalogComponent,
        children: [
            { path: "", component: EmptyComponent },
            //{ path: "report/:id", component: ReportDetailsComponent, data: { create: false } },
            { path: "report", component: ReportDetailsComponent, data: { create: true } }
        ]
    }
];
```

What exactly could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: I seem to have narrowed the cause down, but I am not sure why it's doing this. The simple fact that I'm including another directive in my list of directives is causing this issue. Even stripping that directive down to bare bones do nothing... it's preventing the parent template from rendering.

Answer (score 0):

So after much further digging and attempts at simplifying the issue, I think I have encountered the cause of this.

My parent path had included a directive in it, which was referenced as follows.

```
import { ReportTileComponent } from "./index";
```

The solution to fix this, it seems at least after removing all other potential issues, is to directly reference the component.

```
import { ReportTileComponent } from "./main/report-tile.component";
```

The reasoning for this perplexes me tremendously, but it solved my issue.

Comment: I have seen it mentioned that the order of the exports in `index.ts` is sometimes significant but didn't run into this myself yet.